# Define rootscope variable in an .ASPX file

Tags: asp.net, typescript, angularjs-rootscope

I am trying to define an AngularJS rootscope variable in a .ASPX file to use in a TypeScript file, but I am unsure of how to do this. I am open to any way to be able to define a value in an .ASPX file and use it in TypeScript, so any other suggestion will work for me.

Comment: Do you already have access to `$rootScope` in your .ASPX file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to tell TypeScript that the property is there, you can extend the rootScope interface:

```
interface extendedRootScope extends ng.IRootScopeService {
    myProp: number;
}
```

Then when you inject `$rootScope` in your controller, type it as your new interface:

```
export class MyController {
    constructor(private $rootScope: extendedRootScope) { }

    someMethod() {
        // Access this.$rootScope.myProp
    }
}
```

If you need to access `$rootScope` from outside the Angular world (like in your ASPX page) to add the property, you can do something like this:

```
<script>
    var injector = angular.element('[ng-app]').injector();
    var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');

    $rootScope.myProp = 1;
</script>
```

This assumes you are using `ng-app` to initialize your Angular app.

Similarly, you could create an Angular service on the fly in a script tag, inject `$rootScope` into that service, and add properties to it.

Comment: Thanks, I used the second suggestion and it works great!